# Passing file as an argument into my program and then into a function?

Tags: c, function, file, pointers

I am using CodeBlocks to create my program in C and I'm having trouble with the following issue.

I am trying to open and read from a .txt file and it works fine if I put it into the main function like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

FILE *input;

input = fopen("file.txt", "r");

char singleLine[50];

while(!feof(input)){

fgets(singleLine, 50, input);
puts(singleLine);
}
```

However, if I set the name of the file "file.txt" as an argument in CodeBlock using the "Set Program's Arguments option, and then want to pass it into a function that would read from it like this:

```
void read(char *name){

File *input;

....
....

}
```

And call it like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


read(&argv[1]);

}
```

It does not work and the program crashes.

Comment: Please see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2173917)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your function prototyope is

```
void read(char *name)
```

then you need to call it like

```
read(argv[1]);
```

because , `argv[1]` itself gives you a `char *`, not `&argv[1]`.

FWIW, always check for the validity of `argv[n]` before using it directly.

Comment: Hey there and thanks for your reply!I definitely made a mistake there but it still does not work. Maybe something to do with the location of the file?

Comment: @Daeto after checking `argc > 1` try printing the file name in `main() `and again in `read()`. You must also test `input == NULL` after attempting to open the file. Finally please don't use `read()` as a function name - it's already used for a library function.

Comment: The printf function prints the name of the file both in main and in the read function so I guess passing the name of the file as an argument is not being an issue here. However, I added the condition to check whether opening the file was successful, it it turns out that it was not. Any idea why? The commands in the function look just like I described them above in main.

Comment: @Daeto you are opening the file for reading, so it must it already exist, on a path that the program will look in.

Comment: @Daeto you have shown code for what worked, but you didn't show the code for what did not work.

Comment: Oh I think I just figured it out! Inside the function for reading, when I was trying to open the file instead of writing fopen(filename, "r"); I was writing fopen("filename", "r"); Now it works properly. So when passing the file as an argument, if I were to open it inside main function, I would then write fopen(argv[1], "r"); and I only put the name of the file into quotation marks when I know I want to open that one particular file, right? But the file in the argument can change.

Answer (score 0):

Test

```
read(&argv[0]);
```

and see what is in argv in console

```
printf(&argv[0]);
```

Comment: I'm confused. Sourav said I should not be passing arguments into the read function like this. Also, argv[0] is the location of my program isn' t it? Why would I need that? If I print argv[1], it prints file.txt which is the name of the file located in the same directory as my program. So I guess it is really there.

Comment: `printf(&argv[0]);` is really a _bad_ example, even ignoring the logic, whatsoever.